# как использовать PATH в модуле cx-freeze?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, cx-freeze

как использовать PATH в модуле cxfreeze?
есть скрипт, использующий selenium webdriver:

```
def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/ChekingClients/chromedriver')
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver
```

Хочу сделать его (скрипт) исполняемым, но не понимаю как прописать параметры установки, чтобы webdriver (Chrome) прописался в PATH?

Создал setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

base = None

executables = [Executable("INN_FL.py", base=base)]
add_to_path = True

#packages = ["idna"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'path': sys.path + ['modules']
    }
}

setup(
    name = "GetInn>",
    #options = options,
    version = "1.0",
    description = 'GetPersonInn',
    executables = executables,
    options = options
```

Но при запуске на другой машине ругается:
[image: Ошибка в командной строке]

Comment: Кажется у вас приведён не весь код вывода консоли. Попробуйте его в файл перенаправить

Comment: @unick еще бы я понимал как это сделать... В моем понимании он мне ругается, что chromedriver не прописан в PATH. В документации про PATH крайне скупо написано :(